# Setting array for json in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to output the following with the

```
data: [{ rank: 2, state: 1, count: 3, }, { rank: 2, state: 3, count: 3, }, { rank: 1, state: 1, count: 2, }, { rank: 11, state: 4, count: 2, },],
```

but I'm getting extra [] & {} with the following code.

```
data: [[{rank: "2"},{state: "3"},{count: "3"},],[{rank: "2"},{state: "1"},{count: "3"},],[{rank: "1"},{state: "1"},{count: "2"},],[{rank: "11"},{state: "4"},{count: "2"},],],
```

Tried with many format to store the data without creating extra braces but not sure where is generating it. This is my code:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= (sizeof($dataDB)/3); $i++){
        $d_temp = [];
        foreach ($dataDB as $k => $v) {
            $ks = explode("_", $k);
            $k1 = $ks[0];
            $k2 = $ks[1];
            if ($k1 == $i) {
                $d_temp[] = [ $k2 => $v ];
            }
        }
        $data[] = $d_temp;
    }
```

Except this method, what's the way to store the named array without extra {} in between?

Comment: change this `$d_temp[] = [ $k2 => $v ];`  to `$d_temp = [ $k2 => $v ];`

Comment: @MustafaPoya Wouldn't that override `$d_temp` on every iteration?

Comment: Yes, it's overriding the d_temp on every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$d_temp[] = [$k2 => $v];` for `$d_temp[$k2] = $v;`

Check the bracketing.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you add **$d_temp** as the first element in the **$data** array.

Solution:

```
$data = $d_temp;
```

Or do not use the array $data, but just get $d_temp

Comment: No, it's not working. With this i'm getting the first set of foreach only.